# Pachi cant find caffe/caffe.hpp: No such file or directory

Tags: makefile, caffe

I am attempting to compile Go/Baduk engine Pachi (https://github.com/pasky/pachi) with Caffe (http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org) support.

Caffe install is OK and its located in /something/PACHI_GO_ENGINE/caffe/

caffe.hpp is located in:

```
   /something/PACHI_GO_ENGINE/caffe/distribute/include/caffe/caffe.hpp
   /something/PACHI_GO_ENGINE/caffe/include/caffe/caffe.hpp
```

I also updated the Pachi Makefile as instructed:

```
  - Edit Makefile, set DCNN=1, point it to where caffe is installed and build.
```

I even made a copy of ...include/caffe/ to /usr/local/lib because this supposed to be a default location.

Makefile changes:

```
DCNN=1
#CAFFE_LIB=/usr/local/lib
CAFFE_LIB=/something/PACHI_GO_ENGINE/caffe/distribute/include 
#(and several variations of this)
```

And I still get:

```
[CC]   fbook.c
[CC]   chat.c
[CXX]   dcnn.cpp
dcnn.cpp:13:27: fatal error: caffe/caffe.hpp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Makefile.lib:78: recipe for target 'dcnn.o' failed
make: *** [dcnn.o] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0):

`CAFFE_LIB` variable is to point to the path where caffe.so or caffe.a is present. In your case, the `dcnn.cpp` cannot find the header files.

Though the header files are present in `/something/PACHI_GO_ENGINE/caffe/distribute/include` they won't be detected by `pachi` because, header file paths are mentioned using the variable `INCLUDES`. You will have to append this path to the `INCLUDES` variable and not the `CAFFE_LIB`.

Comment: You can see the file here: https://github.com/pasky/pachi/blob/master/Makefile

How can I append it?

Comment: You can see the file here: https://github.com/pasky/pachi/blob/master/Makefile



I added:


        INCLUDES=-I. -I/mnt/kolakas1/BLAAH/PACHI_GO_ENGINE/caffe/include


but now I got a next error: 


[CC]   fbook.c
[CC]   chat.c
[CXX]   dcnn.cpp
[CC]   pachi.c
[LINK] pachi
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcaffe
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:159: recipe for target 'pachi' failed
make: *** [pachi] Error 1